# Let moderators use blocked tags on historical questions

Tags: feature-request, edits, moderator-tools, blocked-tags

The Stack Exchange team has the ability to block a tag *even when the tag still exists*. With the combination of Shog's new tag-specific popup messages, some tags which are blocked now have messages that accompany *why* they are blocked. The tag is still kept around for those questions which have historical significance.

Sometimes, though, those questions are pretty terrible. Most notably, they have *really bad* titles that we'd like to clean up. Problem is, since the tag is blocked, we can't successfully make any edits on the question itself without removing the tag from the question. But that kind of defeats the purpose of this feature, since it is meant to **keep the tag alive** as a category that is no longer on-topic, for these historical questions.

I've thought of a few possible solutions to this:

1. Give moderators the ability to edit the question and ignore the list of blocked tags as long as the tag was already on the question.
2. Let moderators add a blocked tag to a question if the tag still exists on the site (hasn't been completely destroyed yet). Basically, any tag that exists for historical purposes.
3. If those two are too complicated to implement, just let moderators use blocked tags. (Do you trust us enough not to re-invent the homework tag?)

**Note:** This is a request for the privilege to be given to *moderators only*, not all users in general. Just for clarification. This would pretty much only be used on historically locked questions that can only be edited by moderators anyways.

Comment: Huh, I thought the purpose was to prevent new questions with the tag while we kill it.. like [installation](http://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/installation) on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @ɥʇǝS [Not anymore.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275759)

Comment: If the tag both is necessary and forbidden, shouldn't that should be an argument to delete the questions (migrate them to [codegolf.se] — since that seems to be your use case — or archive them on StackPrinter)?

Answer (score 1):

Meh; easy solution here is just to disable the blocklist until/unless the tag is cleaned up and in an "archive-only" state.

So I've done that. Edit away...

Comment: speaking of troublesome tags... is there anything else needed in this [request for tag tips at Programmers meta](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6983/improve-question-quality-by-informing-askers-of-expectations-in-some-career-rela) to get it implemented? (feel free to remove this comment upon reading)

Comment: needs me to get through a backlog of similar stuff, @gnat - otherwise, looks fine; a bit too wordy perhaps, we'll see what it looks like in the UI.